# Java EE deployment error

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jakarta-ee, glassfish

While deploying a particular project I'm getting deployment error like "module has not been deployed"... but I'm able to deploy other projects... the error shown is as follows

```
In-place deployment at F:\onlineexam_1\build\web
deploy?path=F:\onlineexam_1\build\web&name=onlineexam_1&force=true failed on GlassFish v3 Domain
F:\onlineexam_1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:577: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Build was successful. Problem occurred when I used the Subversion and Netbeans copy my project to new folder. Problem will be probably in bad paths in `build-impl.xml`

```
576 <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
577    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
578 </target>
```

I'm going create a new project and copy all files there.. screw it.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting Catalina folder from work and conf folders of your web server if you use tomcat.

Comment: it's tagged as a glassfish question so I'm guessing he's not using tomcat